# SQL sub-select returns 2 columns - expected 1

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
sqlite> SELECT *
   ...> FROM Studio
   ...> WHERE third_party_id NOT IN (
   ...> SELECT third_party_id,effeciency_rating
   ...> FROM Staff
   ...> WHERE Staff.third_party_id = Studio.third_party_id AND
   ...> Staff.effeciency_rating < 0.7
   ...> );
```

with the error message

> sub-select returns 2 columns - expected 1

So I know why this happens, my subselct has thirdpartyid and effeciency rating while I only select thirdpartyid from Studio.

So my relation: Stuido employs staff
So now I want to select all studios that didnt employ a staff with effeciency rating under 0.7.

So my question is how do I select my staff based on effeciency rating and give my studio back?

Comment: remove `effeciency_rating` which in `NOT IN` select subquery

Comment: You should always specify the column(s) you want to return rather than using `*`

Comment: This is not a forum but a Q&A site. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would just do:

```
SELECT st.*
FROM Studio st
WHERE st.third_party_id NOT IN (SELECT s.third_party_id
                                FROM Staff s
                                WHERE s.third_party_id = st.third_party_id AND s.effeciency_rating < 0.7
                               );
```

Note that I introduced table aliases and qualified all the column names so the query is unambiguous.  However, as written, the query doesn't really make sense.  I suspect that you want `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT st.*
FROM Studio st
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT s.third_party_id
                  FROM Staff s
                  WHERE s.third_party_id = st.third_party_id AND s.effeciency_rating < 0.7
                 );
```

In any case, I recommend `NOT EXISTS` over `NOT IN` because it handles `NULL` values more sensibly.

Answer (score 1):

Your inner query has 2 columns defined

**third_party_id,effeciency_rating**

remove the effeciency_rating column from the inner select.

[See example and tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
...> SELECT third_party_id,effeciency_rating
```

To:

```
...> SELECT third_party_id
```

Comment: As a side note, I believe you have misspelled efficiency :)